# Is there a way to replace/append cell data over cell data from a Data Source

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have an excel Macro that I've "Inherited" I'm not very familiar with VBA so the exact specifics of figuring out what is wrong with this code has become a slight problem, There's a Column (Column F) in a Table that has a Comments section. This comment section is suppose to be persistent through the data refreshes being performed. (If I add a comment to an entry despite the data source's comment section being empty it should keep the comments I added previously) According to my Supervisor this used to work but in the past 6 months has stopped working and I believe it may've been due to a bad edit or modification of the macro

I've already edited the code to work with my new Data Connection, and I've corrected it some to properly handle the data now but this comment function is missing and I can tell there is a section of the code that handles the column and section but I can't tell what's wrong with it.

```
Sub RefreshAndDelete()
'
'
'
'

    Dim sht as Sheets
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim col as Columns
    Dim row as Rows
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set sht = Sheets("Ready Board")
    sht.Visible = True
    sht.Cells.Select
    If (sht.AutoFilterMode And sht.FilterMode) or sht.FilterMode Then
    sht.ShowAllData
    End If
    set col = Columns("A:F")
    set rng = Range("IE_Testing_Board[[#Headers],[Comments]]")
    col.Copy
    Sheets.Add, Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Raw Data"
    ActivateSheet.Paste
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    set col = Columns("A:A")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    col.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    set rng = Range("A2")
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[4]&RC[3]&RC[2]"
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Select
    rng.End(xlDown).Select
    rng.Offset(0,-1).Select
    set rng =  Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp))
    rng.FillDown
    set rng = Range("F1")
    set rng = rng.Offset(1,0)
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
    set rng = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
    rng.Offset(0,2)
    rng.ClearContents
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    sht.ListObjectsListObjects("IE_Testing_Board").Range.AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:="Yes"
    If Criteria1 <> "" Then
    set row = Rows("1:1")
    row.Offset(1,0)
    set rng = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
    rng.EntireRow.RefreshAndDelete
    sht.ListObjects("IE_Testing_Board").Range.AutoFilter field:=11
    Else
    sht..ListObjects("IE_Testing_Board").Range.AutoFilter field:=11
    End If
    set rng = Range("F1").Offset(1,0)
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Part '#]]&[@[Operation '#]]&[@[Machine '#]],'Raw Data'!C[-5]:C[1],7,FALSE),"""")"
    set rng = Range("E1").Offset(1,0)
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Part '#]]&[@[Operation '#]]&[@[Machine '#]],'Raw Data'!C[-4]:C[1],6,FALSE),"""")"
    set rng = Range("F2")
    rng.AutoFill Destination:=Range("IE_Testing_Board[Comments]")
    sht.ListObjects("IE_Testing_Board").Range.AutoFilter field:=6, _
        Criteria1:="0"
    set rng = Range("F1").Offset(1,0)
    set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
    rng.ClearContents
    sht.ListObjects("IE_Testing_Board").Range.AutoFilter field:=6
    set rng = Range("E2")
    rng.AutoFill Destination:=Range("IE_Testing_Board[Part Program]")
    sht.ListObjects("IE_Testing_Board").Range.AutoFilter field:=5, _
        Criteria1:="0"
    set rng = Range("E1").Offset(1,0)
    set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
    rng.ClearContents
    sht.ListObjects("IE_Testing_Board").Range.AutoFilter field:=5
    set rng = Range("IE_Testing_Board[Comments]")
    rng.Copy
    set rng = Range("F2")
    rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    set rng = Range("IE_Testing_Board[Part Program]")
    rng.Copy
    set rng = Range("E2")
    rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    set rng = Range("E2")
    sht.Visible = False
    set sht = Sheets("Raw Data")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    sht.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    set sht = Sheets("Home")

End Sub
```

My Expected Result is that the Table Column: "Comments" (Which is column F) keeps whatever is entered into it despite the information pulled from the data source on our SharePoint.

So, If on my SharePoint the Comment cell it has "ID-0001" but in my Excel file it has the Comment - "Needs Approval" when the data is refreshed via the Macro it should somehow keep the "Needs Approval" comment that is in the file. Appending the File's Comment to the SharePoint Data's comment. (Even if they're blank it should still keep the File's comment).

If any more clarification is needed I'll do my best to Provide it.

Comment: oh boy. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to get rid of all the `.Select` & `.ActiveCell` in your code. The length of this can prob be shrunk 4 fold by just doing that. After, debugging is much more bearable

Comment: I'm not lying when I'm saying I "Inherited" this Macro, I just need it to work now. I'll take a crack at reducing it as much as possible but I can't honestly say I know what i'm doing, I'm not acquainted with VBA well enough but I'll take a crack at it nonetheless.

Comment: Err, okay. So I've been attempting to make heads or tails of getting rid of the `.Select` &  `.ActiveCell` this but I've just broken the code repeatedly.. I'm not sure I'm succeeding in any step other than making the problem bigger.

Comment: @urdearboy okay, So bear with me here. I "finished' trying to remove the bits, I guarantee it probably isn't good.. but I added it to the post.